# Application to identify which chord could it be by given notes

Tags: music

Is there any application which can tell which can tell in which chord could selected notes be?

I am having troubles with arranging songs. When I get basic melody by ear and then want to add bass or fills, I spend to much time trying different notes, while I know those bass and fills almost always belong to the chord of the melody in particular lick.  I can count all possible chords mathematically, but it also takes some time.  I'm not good to find it out by ear yet.

Basically, I want some application where I can click on some notes on guitar and it would show all possible chords which those notes could belong to and then when I click any of those chords it would show which notes are also inside this chord (for fills and bass).

Comment: What operating system should it run on?

Comment: @Undo it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

One free application that is accessible online is Ultimate Chord Finder For Guitar and Piano and can be found by clicking this link [Free On Line Chord Finder](http://www.scales-chords.com/chord-finder-guitar-piano.php)

You just enter the notes and it will tell you all the possible chord names that contain those notes.

Good luck.

Comment: I've seen it, but it's not very userfriendly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free application called **[Teach Me Guitar](https://github.com/souparno/Teach-Me-Guitar)** that I have developed.

I use this to determine the scale and chords of a song from the notes.

Answer (score 0):

**Chord.Rocks** has several tools for finding notes in chords/scales. it is a free website and will work on any computer or device.

To find notes that go along with chords as you mentioned above, the best thing to do would be to go to the "Identify Scale" page and select all notes in your chords. A number of scales will pop up. Click "View" on one to see all notes and chords in the scale.

http://chord.rocks/guitar/identify-scale

It also has a reverse chord finder, if you're only looking up a single chord at a time, not the whole scale.

http://chord.rocks/guitar/identify-chord

Comment: What is your affiliation with that website? Please disclose.